# How make url from two get value and use one in urlbar by htaccess or php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can make

```
post.php?post_id=1&post_url='demo-url'
```

to

```
1/demo-url
```

by .htaccess and this is the code of htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ post.php?post_id=$1&post_url=$2 [NC,L]
```

Now I want to create an url which will remove 1 or post_id from the url just show the post url like

```
/demo-url
```

I've checked all of the stackoverflow problem but can't find it. I think htaccess can create that or if that can't then tell me which will be my php code to solve that problem...
Can any one help me to solve the problem?

Comment: is post_id always be 1?

Comment: Its not possible because  post_id=1 how call this.

Comment: Remove ([0-9]+)/ and post_id=$1& and replace $2 with $1 ...

Comment: 1 solution your post_id=1 always

Comment: No it is changeable from database. I've just given the demo

Comment: Your answer is not fully clear @Jonas. I want to create for my every post by http://domain.com/demo-title. Or if I make them only by this: post.php?post_url='demo-title' . That means not give my post_id to search the post. Is it first or slow search from the database